# PHPMailer SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host / using smtp.gmail.com server

Tags: php, laravel-8, phpmailer

Based on the youtube video I watch on how to perform smtp configuration using smtp.gmail.com

Below are my code:

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'example@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '************';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 25;                                    

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('target@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

I get this error when I try to run this code:

`php email.php`

The error are:

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 10060 Additional SMTP info: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I tried remake the app password in my gmail account and retry to deploy it again but get the same error. I wanted to try this first before implement it in my system

Comment: Try with `$mail->Port = 587` instead of 25

Comment: i tried     

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587; 

but still the same error

Comment: Have you tried disabling firewall if any?

Comment: What happened when you tried [the diagnostic advice in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, but I am unable to connect to the SMTP host just now because of network restriction at workplace that I am not authorized to modify. 

Everything ran smoothly when I used port 587 to run my code at home. Thank you amigos